# Copy to clipboard using HTML5 Clipboard API by clicking on jQuery DOM?

Tags: jquery, html

I do not want to use flash, but utilize the new HTML5 Clipboard API.

I want to fire the copy event by clicking on `$('.link-copy')`

How do i do this? I can't seem to find a working example.

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of how to do this:

**HTML**:

```
<p id="p">Some random text</p>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
copyContent = function (el) {
    // Create a temporary element
    var $tmp = $("<input />");
    // Add the temp el to the DOM
    $("body").append($tmp);
    // Add the text to the temp el and select it
    $tmp.val($(el).text()).select();
    // Tell the broswer to copy the selection
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // Remove the temporary element
    $tmp.remove();
}
```

Execute on `click`

```
$('.link-copy').on('click', function() {
    copyContent('#p');
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mhjgf2nz/1/)

Comment: This is simple, and works. Also i like that it's a function.